# RavenDB Index Prefix

Tags: ravendb

Since I don't yet have the ability to promote a temp index in Raven Studio (using build 573), I created two indexes manually. It seems to have worked well, but I have a question about the prefixes on each index: Temp, Auto, Raven. Is there anything special about those keywords? When I create my own index, should I use a prefix like that? For now, when I created my index, I used the index name from the temp index and replaced the word Temp with Manual.

Is that an acceptable approach? Should I be using a certain prefix?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bob,
The names are just names, they are there for humans, not for RavenDB.
Indexes starting with Raven/ are reserved, and may be overwritten by the system at some point.
Indexes starting with Auto/ or Temp/ may be generated by the system, and may overwrite an existing index.

Answer (score 2):

I generally use the collection/entity name as prefix before just so that helps me  visually to understand right away what entity the index is primarily based on. If I had index for getting latest list of movies. I would name it Movie/GetLatestIndex..

Comment: I like that. I may go with that, but I'd like to see if someone else can explain if there is any significance to that prefix. Thanks!

Comment: For example, would it be bad if I used "Auto" or "Raven" as a prefix to my own index?

Comment: @Bob, yes don't use "Auto" or "Raven", at best RavenDB will prevent you from doing it. At worse it won't, but bad things might happen further down the line